# Untrusted Host in symfony call

Tags: proxy, centos, symfony4

I installed a symfony application in a centos server that it is behind a proxy and when I try to reach it from an external pc I receive this error: `Untrusted Host "192.168.43.218"` and below that `in public/index.php (line 37) $response = $kernel->handle($request);`

I tried to follow [this guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html) but nothing happens...Also my index.php is different than the one in the example. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Solved, I had to insert in framework.yaml the `trusted_hosts:  ['192.168.43.218', '192.168.43.218']` command (the ip of the server)